# How do I stop rake from treating a file dependency as a possible task name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

**Short version:**

I have a problem: a file dependency I need for one rake task matches the name of another rake task, so instead of depending on the file, rake tries to depend on the task with the matching name.

***How do I tell rake to only match a dependency to a file?*** Is there some other way out?

**Long version**:

I'm trying to create a rake task in my Rails application that zips up all the files I care about. That's it. Easy.

I'd also appreciate the normal dependency testing in rake: if no files have changed and the zip file already exists, don't do anything.

The issue is that one of the files that I want to include in the zip file (and thus treat as a task dependency) is the `test` directory, but `rake test` happens to be an existing rake task. If I say something like:

```
# FILES_TO_INCLUDE being a Rake::FileList...
file 'output.zip' => FILES_TO_INCLUDE.to_a do
  ...
end
```

rake ends up running `rake test` as well.

Since I add files all the time, and since Rails changes the built-in rake tasks every now and then, I can never be sure that there won't be a conflict between rake tasks and file names.

What can I do to avoid this issue? Is there a better usage of rake that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I observe the same behavior. The `FileTask`, as defined by the `file` method in the rake DSL, inherits from the main Rake `Task` class and, indeed, invoking the dependencies (or in Rake's language `prerequisities`) seems to be the same for `Task`s as well as `FileTask`s, i.e. if a file name is already defined as a rake task, the task is run instead.

The only solution that comes to my mind is to add the path part to the files in `FILES_TO_INCLUDE`. It can be anything as simple as a `"./"` prefix.

So, I'd try this instead:

```
file 'output.zip' => FILES_TO_INCLUDE.map { |file| "./#{file}" } do
  ...
end
```

This approach seems to work OK for me.

Also, for your particular scenario (creating a zip file of some other files), you can actually use a ready-made solution already present in Rake, **the [`PackageTask`](http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/PackageTask.html)**:

```
Rake::PackageTask.new("rake", "1.2.3") do |p|
  p.need_zip = true
  p.package_files.include("lib/**/*.rb")
end
```

This will create a `rake-1.2.3.zip` archive in the `pkg` (configurable) subdirectory. You probably will also need to prefix the files with some directory specification.

Answer (score 0):

My 1st workaround was to avoid symbol names which could be filenames.
E.g. in your case: `task :do_tests` and `directory 'test'` 
CON: does not work without being *always* very careful.

2nd was to use a special syntax for symbol-tasks:  `:@name` 
PRO: Easy to remember, not too much to write.

Now I'm experimenting with a hack, doing the `:@name` - thing automatically.

```rb
    class Object; def rakesym
      self
    end end
    class Symbol; def rakesym
      self.to_s.sub(/\A@?/,'@').to_sym
    end end
    module Rake::DSL
      # transform symbol-tasks and -deps to :@XXXX
      #
      # args is always an array
      # [ t ]
      # [ t, p0 ]       ---> t[p0]
      # [ t, p0,p1 ]    ---> t[p0,p1]
      # [ {t => deps } ]
      # [ t, { [prms] => deps } ]
      # [ t, p0 => deps ]    ---> ERROR
      # [ t, p0,p1 => deps ] ---> ERROR
      # [ t, {[] => deps}
      # [ t, {[params] => deps} ]
      #
      # deps can be a single value or an array:
      #    deps:==   d0 | [] | [d0] | [ d0,d1,.. ]
      def hack_args( *args )
        STDOUT.puts "=== args before: #{args.inspect}"

        args[0] = args[0].rakesym
        if (args[0].is_a? Hash) && (args[0].size == 1)
          t,deps = args[0].first
          args[0] = { t.rakesym => deps }
        end
        if (args[-1].is_a? Hash) && (args[-1].size == 1)
          x, deps = args[-1].first
          deps.map!{|d| d.rakesym } if deps.is_a? Array
          args[-1][x] = deps.rakesym
        end
        STDOUT.puts "=== args after: #{args.inspect}"
        return args
      end

      alias task_o task
      def task(*args, &block )
        task_o( *hack_args(*args), &block )
      end

      # ... same for 'file', 'file_create' and 'directory'

    end # module Rake::DSL
```

Now this gives two different tasks:

```
   desc "create html/ directory"
   directory 'html'
   desc "compile HTML docs"
   task :html => HTML_FILES
```

which I can call from the shell:

```
> rake -D
rake html
    create html/ directory

rake @html
    compile HTML docs
```

**Still TODO:**

- deal with namespaces.
- patch the `defaul_task_name`